# How do I stop my HP PSC printer from writing log files to the root of C?

Tags: windows, printer

My (quite old) HP PSC 1200 series printer insists on writing useless log files named hpfr.xml and hpfrXXXX.log to the root of my C drive; it drives me nuts.  Is there any way to stop it doing so?

Comment: Uninstall the driver and get a new printer.

Comment: @Hello71: I will when this one craps out - and this will be the last HP product I ever own.

Comment: If you do decide to get an HP printer (and BTW, pretty good printers, just WORST DRIVERS EVER), make sure to get a Windows 7 PC. Fairly extensive collection of non-intrusive drivers included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can auto-delete them by adding this line to C:\autoexec.bat

del c:\hpfr*.log

After doing that, your computer will delete any existing log files every time Windows starts.

Comment: Worth a +1 as a work-around.